# A Single Word for "Secretly watching your crush"

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

What is it called, if someone watches their crush from behind without the crush knowing?

I often watch movies in which a guy looks at a girl he likes, happily watching her for some time and pretending to be talking with his friends when the girl looks back or realizes his actions.

Is there a single word for that?

I can't think of another word other than *spying*, which is just wrong, I think.

To be precise:

[image]

Comment: Would "watching surreptitiously" work here ?

Comment: Isn't that the same as "secretly"?

Comment: I think @Prem made a great suggestion. ***Secretly*** is rather generic, like when describing one's password or medical records. ***Surreptitiously*** has a little more nuance, as expounded on here: http://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/surreptitious

Comment: "Stalking" certainly has currency in this space.

Comment: Side-eye.  It's clunky but it works.

Comment: I don't think there is a single word. You just need to explain it. For example, you can say "staring at your crush when they don't look your way."

Comment: @ErnestFriedman-Hill or "creeping [on]"...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think [furtive](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/learner/furtive)/furtively works here.

> behaving in a way that shows that you want to keep something secret and do not want to be noticed

- He looked at her furtively
- He cast a furtive glance towards her.

It doesn't have the negative connotations of spying or stalking.

Comment: "furtive" probably isn't as negative as "spying" or "stalking", but it still definitely carries a negative connotation, e.g. [this dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/furtive) defines it as "secretly (and often dishonestly)".

Answer (score 4):

We also say "to steal a glance".

Comment: That means to take a quick look; the OP asks about watching for some time.